# Completely disable keyboard input when RWin is held down

Tags: windows, autohotkey

Use case: I have a keyboard on which I often accidentaly press the right <kbd>Win</kbd> key, instead of <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>. (FTR, it's an azerty keyboard)

As a result, instead of doing e.g. <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>, which results in typing `{`, I end up doing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>, which results in switching to the 4th window. Pretty annoying.

Thus, I'm now running the following script:

```
RWin::Return
```

It has already improved the situation, as that <kbd>Win</kbd> key is discarded and there is no more window switching.

Though, the key pressed in conjunction with <kbd>Win</kbd> held down still passes through. For example, if I accidentaly press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> (instead of <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>, to type `}`), I end up typing `=`.

I would prefer to completely disable keyboard input when the right <kbd>Win</kbd> is held down, so that any other key pressed would do nothing.

I have done some attempts using `KeyWait` and `BlockInput`, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works here:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

RWin:: 
    ToolTip, RWin pressed, 0, 0
    BlockInput On
return

RWin Up:: 
    BlockInput Off
    ToolTip
return
```

**[Note:](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/BlockInput.htm#Remarks)**

> The OnOff and SendMouse modes might have no effect  if UAC is enabled
> or the script has not been run as administrator.  For more
> information, refer to the [FAQ](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/FAQ.htm#uac).

Comment: Thank you, the solution was to execute as admin. I also managed to get a working script with `BlockInput On` / `KeyWait RWin` / `BlockInput Off` (I don't know if it has caveats compared to your version). Now I have to make the script autostart as admin without UAC prompt, which is doable, but tedious (involves creating a scheduled task).

Comment: "Up" hotkeys and their key-down counterparts always use the keyboard hook.

Comment: I have just tested: `RWin::` uses the keyboard hook. The "KeyWait" variant *might* be more efficient, by having the keyboard hook in background watch for only one action instead of two.